# From spinners to SSD (SQL Database)

Tags: ssd, raid

I have a SQL Server database running on a virtualized Windows Server 2012 R2 (VMware ESXi). I have a task from Accountancy to boost the performance of the database. The database has about 70GB and the RAM allocated is about 90GB. The virtual machine is spining on SAS Disks 10k - RAID10 at the moment. I want to make an upgrade from spinners to SSD but I would like to undertand if this will give a big difference in performance as the uprgade is somewhat expensive as I'm talking about Enterprise SSD. Down bellow I've written what spinners I use at he the moment and the SSD that will be bought eventualy, the SSD's will be used in RAID10. I would like to ask you to help me understand if the upgrade will give me the needed boost in performance? Thank you.

Hardware-
Server: Lenovo x3650 M5
CPU: 2x - Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4 10Cores 2.2 GHz 25MB
RAM: 128 GB
Storage: Lenovo Storwize V3700 V2 (SAS Disks 10k - RAID10)

**What I Have:**
IBM (Seagate ST900MM0168 900GB 10K RPM 12Gbps 2.5" SAS Hard Drive)

Brand: IBM
Model: 01EJ586
Capacity: 900Gb
Interface: SAS 2.5 inch
Data Transfer Rate: 12Gb/s
Rotational Speed: 10,000rpm
External Transfer Rate: 1200 MB/s
Sustained Transfer Rate (Outer to Inner Diameter): 215 to 108 MB/s
Average Latency: 2.9ms
Average Seek Time: 4.6ms
Internal Cache: 128Mb
Hot-swappable: Yes
Caddie: Yes

**The Upgrade:**
IBM AS7J 1.6TB 12G SAS 2.5" MLC G3HS Enterprise SSD

Based on proven HGST Ultrastar SSD1600MM drive technology
Uses 20 nm Multi-Level Cell (MLC) NAND flash memory
Part number - 2.5" G3HS: 00FN409
Interface: 12 Gbps SAS
Capacity: 1.6 TB
Endurance (drivewrites per day over 5 years): 10 DWPD
Endurance (total bytes written): 29.2 PB
Data reliability: 1 in 10(17) bits read
MTBF: 2,500,000 hours (0.35% AFR)
IOPS reads (4 KB blocks): 130,000
IOPS writes (4 KB blocks): 100,000
Sequential read rate (64 KB blocks): 1100 MBps
Sequential write rate (64 KB blocks): 765 MBps
Read latency (seq): 100 µs
Write latency (seq): 45 µs

Comment: What database system, edition, version?

Comment: I’d wager it’s not going to make as much difference as you will hope, if anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to approach this by figuring out where the time for your critical processes is going (the ones that you want to improve the performance of). Look at execution plans, wait stats, sp_whoisactive to get a picture of what this is going to be.

You have more memory than data, which means that there is a possibility that your disk usage is quite low and your important data is being serviced purely through memory.

If IO isn’t where your time is going then improving your IO performance is going to do nothing to help. At the worst case going to move more of your workload to CPU. This could give you a situation where you’ve spent money on better hardware but things get slower. No one likes to admit these observations. Cary Millsap calls this performance scenario a Yeti situation - an observation that makes little sense on the surface.